# acts as votable rails ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound and NoMethodError in ArticlesController

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, nomethoderror, acts-as-votable

I've finished a Udemy course on making a Blog App in Rails. I've added JSON functionality for mobile viewing of articles and sign up/logging in. All working.

My next problem is I want to add upvotes and downvotes so logged in users can vote on articles.

I have installed acts_as_votable gem and followed a tute (http://www.mattmorgante.com/technology/votable) how to implement it but I am getting the following errors when a user clicks on upvote/downvote:
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound or NoMethodError in ArticlesController

I'm guessing the first error is because the article controller already knows which article i'm talking about when i click upvote? So I commented that out for downvote_by and it doesn't know the method downvote_by

What have I missed? Appreciate the help. Thanks.

If I click Upvote:

[image]

If I click Downvote:
[image]

Articles controller:

```
    class ArticlesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!, :except => [:index, :show]
  before_filter :set_article, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  def index
    @articles = Article.all
  end

  def new
    @article = Article.new
  end

  def create
    @article = current_user.articles.build(article_params)
    if @article.save
      flash[:success] = "Article has been created"
      redirect_to articles_path
    else
      flash.now[:danger] = "Article has not been created"
      render :new
    end
  end

  def edit
    if @article.user != current_user
      flash[:danger] = "You can only edit your own article"
      redirect_to root_path
    end
  end 

  def update
    if @article.user != current_user
      flash[:danger] = "You can only edit your own article"
      redirect_to root_path
    else
      if @article.update(article_params)
          flash[:success] = "Article has been updated"
          redirect_to @article
      else
        flash.now[:danger] = "Article has not been updated"
        render :edit
      end
    end
  end

  def show
    @comment = @article.comments.build
  end 

  def destroy
    if @article.destroy
      flash[:success] = "Article has been deleted"
      redirect_to articles_path
    end
  end
  def upvote
    @article=Article.find(params[:id])
    @article.upvote_by current_user
    flash[:success] = "Successfully liked"
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html {redirect_to articles_path }
      format.json { render json: { count: @article.liked_count } }
    end
  end
  def downvote
    #@article = Article.find(params[:id])
    @article.downvote_by current_user
    flash[:success] = "Successfully disliked"
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html {redirect_to articles_path }
      format.json { render json: { count: @article.disliked_count } }
    end
  end

  private 
    def article_params
      params.require(:article).permit(:title, :body)
    end

    def set_article
    @article=Article.find(params[:id])
    end
end
```

show.html.erb file that concerns the likes/dislikes:

```
<div class="article-body">
<%= link_to article_like_path(@article), method: :put do %>
  Upvote
    <%= @article.get_upvotes.size %>
<% end %>
<%= link_to article_dislike_path(@article), method: :put do %>
  Downvote
    <%= @article.get_downvotes.size %>
<% end %>
```

Article model:

```
    class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :title, presence: true
  validates :body, presence: true

  belongs_to :user
  acts_as_votable
  has_many :comments, dependent: :destroy

  default_scope { order(created_at: :desc)}
end
```

routes file:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  devise_for :users, :controllers => {registrations: "registrations", sessions: "sessions", :omniauth_callbacks => "callbacks"}
  # The priority is based upon order of creation: first created -> highest priority.
  # See how all your routes lay out with "rake routes".

  #namespace :api, defaults: {format: :json} do
  #  scope :v1 do
  #    mount_devise_token_auth_for 'User', at: 'auth', skip: [:omniauth_callbacks]
      # :controllers => { :sessions => "api/v1/sessions" }, 
  #  end
  #end

  # You can have the root of your site routed with "root"
  root to: 'articles#index'
  resources :articles do
    put "like", to: "articles#upvote"
    put "dislike", to: "articles#downvote"
    resources :comments
  end
  end
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove this code line from `upvote` and `downvote` actions in your controller:

```
@article = Article.find(params[:id])
```

> *watch the spaces between the equal sign*

Edit your `before_filter` to this:

```
before_action :set_article, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy, :upvote, :downvote]
```

Your routes should be :

```
resources :articles do
  member do
    put "like", to: "articles#upvote"
    put "dislike", to: "articles#downvote"
  end
    resources :comments
end
```

Comment: Champ! thanks heaps. In my show.html.erb I had to change the paths to:  <%= link_to like_article_path and  <%= link_to dislike_article_path